# Echoing html if data from SQL if statement true

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I've been struggling at how to echo this set of HTML with users that are set as admin from my database. I've looked at quite a few places for information but I'm struggling to get it to work. Perhaps I'm doing something really stupid. Thanks for your help.

```
<?php
                  $steamidb =&$steamprofile['steamid'];

                  $steamhextoid=dechex($steamidb);
                  $steamstart = 'steam:';
                  $steamhextoidfin = $steamstart . '' . $steamhextoid;


                        $sql = "SELECT group FROM users WHERE identifier='".$steamhextoidfin."'";
                        $result = $conn->query($sql);
                        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
                        // output data of each row
                  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
                     if($row['group'] == 'admin')
                     {
                       echo '<li class="sub-menu">
                           <a href="javascript:;" >
                               <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
                               <span>Admin</span>
                           </a>
                           <!--<ul class="sub">
                               <li><a  href="#">COMING SOON</a></li>
                               <li><a  href="buttons.html">Buttons</a></li>
                               <li><a  href="panels.html">Panels</a></li>
                           </ul>-->
                       </li>';
                     }


                     else {
                  echo "Error";
                }
}

                  ?>
```

Comment: are you sure $row['group'] == 'admin' is true? are you getting the echo "Error"; output

Comment: another question, did you inspeact the source in the browser to see if it is not there? The reason I ask is because you may be styling the span out of view, yet the html might actually be there. also, was the <span> suppose to be inside the <i>?

Comment: Hey @Piyper 

Sorry I should have stated, I'm not getting any output from either and yes I have set group as admin. And I'm not seeing the html anywhere in the source.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken? I would go from top to bottom commenting out the if statements to see if any data is being returned at all from the query first then add the if statements back in one at a time to see if data is returned with each new condition to see where the root of the issue is. It's one thing if that statement is not evaluating to true, it's another if no data is returned at all from the initial query execution. I also hard-code in variables sometimes to make sure the issue isn't because my variables aren't being set properly from the top of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot to put the while between {}. Here is the correct code:

```
<?php
              $steamidb =&$steamprofile['steamid'];

              $steamhextoid=dechex($steamidb);
              $steamstart = 'steam:';
              $steamhextoidfin = $steamstart . '' . $steamhextoid;


                    $sql = "SELECT group FROM users WHERE identifier='".$steamhextoidfin."'";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
                    // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                            {
                                if($row['group'] == 'admin')
                                    {
                                        echo '<li class="sub-menu">
                                                <a href="javascript:;" >
                                                    <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
                                                    <span>Admin</span>
                                                </a>
                                                <!--<ul class="sub">
                                                        <li><a  href="#">COMING SOON</a></li>
                                                        <li><a  href="buttons.html">Buttons</a></li>
                                                        <li><a  href="panels.html">Panels</a></li>
                                                    </ul>-->
                                                </li>';
                                                 }


                                                 else {
                                              echo "Error";
                                            }
                            }
                    }

              ?>
```